# Manter fork Atualizado no git Hub

Tags: git, github

Entrei no site do GitHub e fiz o Fork de um projeto, porém o Projeto original obteve mudanças, como eu faço pelo site para atualizar o projeto que eu clonei? Gostaria de saber se existe alguma opção pelo site, não em ide's de terceiros, linha de comando e afins...

Answer (score 0):

Sim, existe! Siga os passos abaixo:

1. Abra no navegador a página do repositório que é o seu fork
2. Clique no botão *compare*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

3. Uma nova página será aberta, *Comparing Changes*, e repare você entrou em uma versão do upstream do repositório.
4. Mude a base do *fork* para o seu repositório.
5. Mude o *head fork* para o upstream.

Nesse momento já será possível criar um PR para executar